# Can not create classlib (core) using dotnet CLI

Tags: c#, .net-core, projects-and-solutions, class-library, dotnet-cli

I used the dotnet CLI command `dotnet new classlib -o ProjectName` to create a class library and added the EF Core Package using `dotnet add package` but when I tried to run some `dotnet ef` commands it threw the following error.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcOTx.png)

Later, I realized that `dotnet new classlib` creates **classlib (.netstandard)** instead of creating **classlib (core)**. I would like to know is there anyway to create **classlib (core)** using dotnet CLI or any alternate for **classlib (core)**.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can always use `-h` to check the class lib. So, when you run `dotnet new classlib -h`, you would find an option `-f` to set the framework. Basically, you can run the following if you would like to create a new .net core project:

```
dotnet new classlib -f netcoreapp2.2
```

However, since version 2.2 is just a couple of days old, you might either want to install it or use `dotnet new classlib -f netcoreapp2.1`.

You can also convert your existing netstandard app to .net core by updating the .csproj file.

Comment: It's strange that this question/answer isn't more popular.  I was trying to use DataAnnotations that permit a POCO to declare validation rules.